# Distinguish which on of the buttons with the same value was pressed

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to write an admin panel for a website. The functionality I want to code is simple:
there will be a list of projects and next to the project's name there will be a button called 'edit'. The button will lead the user to another page where he can edit that specific project.

What confuses me is the fact that I can't identify which button was pressed unless I check each one of the buttons specifically (am i right?). It would help if all the buttons have the same name and different value rather than different names and same value.

So is there a way to actually tell which project's button was pressed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you have it set up?  One form with multiple submit buttons that are 'Edit'? Or is each one its own form with a hidden value for the project and an 'edit' submit button?

Comment: Are you trying to find out which button was pressed through JS on the page on which it is pressed, or through PHP on the page it leads to?

Comment: I using php to access it from the page that it leads to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will send value of `value` attribute of `button` element:

```
<button type="submit" name="id" value="123">Edit</button>
```

But if you need to support older versions of IE, you might use arraylike name

```
<input type="submit" name="id[123]" value="Edit" />
```

And access it in php:

```
<?php

$id = key($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: The second idea wasn't working that well. When I tried to echo $id it only ouputed 'Array' and gaving a php error. 

The first idea works perfectly, I hope i won't have much trouble using it. The admin panel will be used in modern browsers only and mostly in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: With second approach, `$_POST['id']` is an array, thats why I also posted `$id = key($_POST['id']);` that is supposed to get current key from this array. If you have used `key` function and still have array on output, than you have something messed up in your form (other element with `name=id[123][123]`?)

Comment: oh I didn't see the key() function :) Works perfectly thanks again!